# Unable to do applyDeltas on Ace Editor in Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, ace-editor

I am trying to update Ace-Code-Editor which I installed from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace-editor

In the API, I'm trying to find `applyDeltas()` given here https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=document but I am unable to find it.

Code Snippet

```
    this._thiscurrentdelta = this.codeeditorservice._currentCode.subscribe(changes => {
      this._changes = changes;
      if(this._last_applied_change != changes){
        this.editor.applyDeltas([changes] // doesn't work
        this.editor.getSession().applyDeltas([changes]) // doesn't work
        this.editor.getSession().getDocument().applyDeltas([changes]) // doesn't work
        this.editor.getDocument().applyDeltas([changes]) // doesn't work 
      }
    });
```

All three approaches keep throwing, "function not found"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the method invokation is different b/w having it used in Node.js and in Angular:

https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor/issues/62

`this.editor.getEditor().sesson.getDocument().applydeltas(event);`